# Multiple dropdownlists in single page

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

I have a Dropdown list DDL1 which contains names (dynamically added).  DDL2,DDL3...7 contains Part Names (bound from data base). My requirement is - Based on the DDL1 selected name I have to display any ONE of the DDLs(2-7) in same page.

The main problem is if I select any part from second DDLs(2-7) I have to display its values(from database) in GridView in the same page. I have successfully completed individual pages for each DDls(2-7). I tried opening in new window based on DDL1 selection successfully, but I want to display in same page. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the problem in same page?
you can do visible true and false for the second ddls. 
and the event will be executed when you change the second ddl...

Comment: Hi RBT, i have tried that but second DDL_TextChanged() is not working. Could you  give me sample code?? Initially only DDl1 will be there in page, based on selection of DDL1 we will display next DDL between 2-7(anyONE), based on selection of next DDL i have to display details from data base to GridView in the same page.

Comment: @KVRKRISHNA could you please paste your current code?

Comment: use the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of dropdownlist and fill other DDLs accordingly? Maybe if you post your code it may be clearer to us.